# Fit one image into another image

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm trying to fit jerry mouse image in the boundary image, but unable to do it

like this
[this i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM4TA.png)

what I have done here is -->

taken one parent div in which I have one image tag with boundary image, and trying to put mickey mouse image in the bacground of boundary image,

my index.html file

```
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <img src= "images/circle-2.png" class = "boundary"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

my app.css file

```
.boundary{
    width : 300px;
    height:  300px;
    width: fit-content;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(./images/mickey.jpeg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 69%;
    background-clip: content-box;

}

div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

Thanku in advance

Comment: background-size: cover;

Comment: Please provide an example of how it should look, a rough sketch is fine. Is the image in the beginning of the question how it looks now, or how it should look?

Comment: yeah added how it should look like in my problem

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using `background-size: contain;`.

```css
.boundary{
    width : 300px;
    height:  300px;
    width: fit-content;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/023/814/090/non_2x/cartoon-character-in-free-png.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
}

div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <img src= "https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/001/192/291/non_2x/circle-png.png" class = "boundary"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this is not working when the image is filled from everywhere, like take a sqaure of blue color, then your code is not working,some content are outside the boundary

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure exactly what the criterias are. The key CSS property/value responsible for the circle is: `border-radius: 50%`.

```css
:root {
  font: 5vmin/1 Consolas;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

figure {
  display: block;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1rem solid rgba(155, 114, 82, 0.7);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/hZj77BZ/lena01.jpg) center center / cover content-box;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <figure></figure>
</main>
```